# Web Form With Smtp Authentication (reply-to)

Tags: php, email, send

My contact form is coming from TEST - as shown in below code but I need it to come from the person completing the form so that when the e-mail is replied to it goes to the address entered, not TEST.

I am new to PHP might I ask help with implementing the Reply-to?  I've tried and keep missing something.

This is my original code.  Thank you!

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

function died($error) {
// your error code can go here
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['contact_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
!isset($_POST['comments'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');   
}

$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z 0-9.'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$contact_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Contact Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {
$error_message .= 'The Telephone # you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
  }
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Contact Name: ".clean_string($contact_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

  require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "TEST<todd@xxxxxx.com>";
$to = "<anyone@xxxxxxxx.com>";
$subject = "Test message";
$body = "$email_message";

$host = "mail.xxxxxxxx.com";
$username = "todd@xxxxxxxx.com";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxx";

headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p></p>");
}
?>


<!-- include your own success html here -->
message sent

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$from = $_POST['contact_name'];
```

Or, if you want their email to appear:

```
$from = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: Thanks.  but this $from must be from the TEST address because of the SMTP Authentication.  That is why I have to set the Reply-To but because of my lack of PHP knowledge I can't get it programmed right.  I'm coping out and looking for help in implementing the reply-to.